# XSLT: How to flatten a structure to XML using XSLT 1

Tags: xml, xslt, structure, flatten

I am trying to flatten a hierarchy / structure to XML using XSLT 1 but not having success. - even finding good links...

input xml

---

```
<Address addressType="R">
 <Structured xmlns="cds_dt">
  <Line1>15 Paradise</Line1>
  <City>Toronto</City>
  <CountrySubdivisionCode>-50</CountrySubdivisionCode>
  <PostalZipCode>
    <PostalCode>A1A1O1</PostalCode>
  </PostalZipCode>
 </Structured>
</Address>
```

desired output xml

---

```
<Address addressType="R">
  <Formatted xmlns="cds_dt">15 Paradise, Toronto, A1A1O1</Formatted>
</Address>
```

I tried this .xsl but no luck - error in file

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:x="cds"> 

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor::address]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::address::Structured]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#44;',.)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="cds_dt">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:Structured">
  <xsl:element name="Formatted" namespace="cds_dt">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(x:Line1, ', ', x:City, ', ', x:PostalZipCode/x:PostalCode)"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Address addressType="R">
    <Structured xmlns="cds_dt">
        <Line1>15 Paradise</Line1>
        <City>Toronto</City>
        <CountrySubdivisionCode>-50</CountrySubdivisionCode>
        <PostalZipCode>
            <PostalCode>A1A1O1</PostalCode>
        </PostalZipCode>
    </Structured>
</Address>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Address addressType="R">
   <Formatted xmlns="cds_dt">15 Paradise, Toronto, A1A1O1</Formatted>
</Address>
```

**Explanation**: Overriding of the [**identity rule**](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) + proper use of namespaces and the **[`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl%3aelement)** instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that:

```
<Address addressType="R">
    <Formatted xmlns="cds_dt">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Line1, ', ', City, PostalZipCode/PostalCode )"/>
    </Formatted>
</Address>
```

Note: I have shortened the paths of the arguments to concat() for readability. So instead of `Line1`, it should actually be `Address/Structured/Line1`.

Comment: Please, don't post untested code -- it doesn't produce the wanted result.